# Google tag manger send all data layer as json

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

I am looking for a way to define all the data layer as variable and send it as is to analytics and from there to BigQuery.

I didn't find a way to deal with all the data layer but only with specific properties within it.

Would appreciate any ideas and direction.

Comment: Can you explain more on why you want to do this way and maybe provide some example? The end of the data flow is BigQuery through GA4. Which make sense. But why you need all parameter?

Comment: As I understand GTM I need to define each variable I send in the data layer also in the GTM UI for it to be sent to the server. I am going to create custom dashboards over the BQ so I prefer to send all the data layer or at least a property of type json as is to the BQ and break it there. This way the events data will be generic and won't require configuration on any change.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got a rough picture about what you are trying to achieve. But unfortunately as far as I know. There is no native way to do it. We still need to pre defined all the parameter keys in the GTM UI as you said. The potential way is create a `custom tag template`. In there you can read the datalayer in JS and send all the object in the datalayer to GA4. But this require a lot JS coding.

Comment: That basically removes all utility from GTM. Why don't you just do a post request to a BQ endpoint and break the data down there without any GTM involved at all?

Comment: @darrelltw this will be quite inconvenient, since custom templates do not support any sort of post request - you'd have to either send a pixel, or request a script, with your serialized JSON as get parameter. That is a less than elegant solution, and a case where one would probably prefer a custom javascript tag over a template.

Comment: I tried to enjoy some of GTM world but work with generic data since we mostly create our own dashboards over BQ.

I guess I will go back to the basics as Eike suggested and send the data directly to BQ.
Thanks

Comment: @yoavba you do not need to define each variable in GA before you send it to bigquery. You need to define it if you want it visible within GA but the big query export will capture whatever event+parameters you send to it.

in regards to gtm you can just use regex .* to capture all events in 1 event tag.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments on your question that this is likely a bad idea for your use case but here's the answer to your question.

`dataLayer` is a regular JavaScript object so to get a JSON representation of it you can use the `JSON.stringify()` method like so:

> JSON.stringify(dataLayer);

This is what the dataLayer representation looks like for me on SO:

```
'[{"0":"consent","1":"default","2":{"ad_storage":"denied","analytics_storage":"denied"}},{"0":"consent","1":"update","2":{"analytics_storage":"denied","ad_storage":"denied"}},{"0":"js","1":"2023-07-17T21:13:52.649Z"},{"0":"config","1":"G-WCZ03SZFCQ","2":{"ads_blocked":false}},{"0":"get","1":"G-WCZ03SZFCQ","2":"client_id"}]'
```

If I push an event e.g. `dataLayer.push({'event': 'test', 'testKey': 'testVal'})`
I will get:

```
'[{"0":"consent","1":"default","2":{"ad_storage":"denied","analytics_storage":"denied"}},{"0":"consent","1":"update","2":{"analytics_storage":"denied","ad_storage":"denied"}},{"0":"js","1":"2023-07-17T21:13:52.649Z"},{"0":"config","1":"G-WCZ03SZFCQ","2":{"ads_blocked":false}},{"0":"get","1":"G-WCZ03SZFCQ","2":"client_id"},{"event":"test","testKey":"testVal"}]'
```

Sending such strings to Google Analytics would quickly face [character limits](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267744?hl=en) so isn't feasible.

Another consideration is the dynamic nature of the dataLayer. It was designed to provide context at the time of a hit/event so you would need to send an updated snapshot of the dataLayer on every change.

If the context of the page is what you need in BigQuery then you might want to define an event in your application such as `setContext` like so:

```
dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'setContext', 'context': { /* some properties */ }});
```

and then extract the properties and send them over to BQ, both via GTM triggered by the `setContext` event.